# Cannot Access Members of Derived Class with shared_ptr of BaseClass

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, polymorphism, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following code that I'm trying to use in polymorphic form using `shared_ptr`.

```
using namespace std;
class Base
{
public:
    int ClassID; // Used only by derived classes
    string Name;
    shared_ptr<Base> Parent;  // For TreeCtrl-like hierarchy
}
class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
    double Length;
    double Width;
    double Height;
}
class DerivedB: public Base
{
public:
    double Radius;
}

class Controller
{
public:
    vector<shared_ptr<Base>> Objects;
    void CreateObject(int class_id, string name, shared_ptr<Base> parent)
    {
        shared_ptr<Base> temp;
        switch(class_id)
        {
        case DERIVEDA: // enum definition assumed
            temp = make_shared<DerivedA>(name, parent); // constructors assumed
            break;
        case DERIVEDB:
            temp = make_shared<DerivedB>(name, parent);
            break;
        }
        Objects.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I check to see whether the polymorphism is working (using VS2013's debugger), I only get the members of the `Base` class (my research is showing that I'm going to have the same problem with the functions).  And using `dynamic_pointer_cast` does not seem to work.  What can I do to gain access to all of the members of the `Derived` class?

Comment: you should use dyncamic_pointer_cast to cast it to the base class , and make all the relevant functions virtual - did you remember to do it?

Comment: ewwww ClassID. This is nearly always the worst possible solution.

Comment: @DavidHaim - I've been having trouble using `dynamic_pointer_cast`.  And right now, there aren't any functions.  Just focusing on the members.

@Puppy - That's mainly for saving to/loading from files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamic_pointer_cast` relies on `dynamic_cast` to work properly. If `dynamic_cast` does  not work, `dynamic_pointer_cast` won't work either.

In your case, `dynamic_cast` won't work since `Base` does not have any `virtual` member functions. Add a `virtual` member function to `Base`, or make the destructor of `Base` a virtual destructor. After that, `dynamic_pointer_cast` should work.

```
class Base
{
  public:

    // Add this.
    virtual ~Base() {}

    int ClassID; // Used only by derived classes
    string Name;
    shared_ptr<Base> Parent;  // For TreeCtrl-like hierarchy
};
```